# How to add a counter to this scheme function

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, sicp

I would like to add a counter so I can see how many times the iteration runs:

```
(define tolerance 0.01)
(define (close-enough? x y) (< (abs (- x y)) 0.001))

(define (fixed-point function starting-guess)
  (define iter-count 0)
  (define (evaluate num)
    ; these lines increment the counter using set!
    (set! iter-count (+ iter-count 1))
    (display iter-count) (display " - ") (display num) (display "\n")
    (let ((next-num (function num)))
      (if (close-enough? num next-num)
          next-num
          (evaluate next-num))))
  (evaluate starting-guess))

(fixed-point cos 1.0)
```

What would be the proper way to do this? Currently I have added in a `define` and a `set!` as I couldn't figure out a way to get `let` to work. Is there a way to do this with `let`, or what's the suggested way to do this?

Or, I suppose another way is to pass it as a parameter to the iteration function itself:

```
(define (fixed-point function starting-guess)
  (define (evaluate num iteration-num)
    (display iteration-num) (display " - ") (display num) (display "\n")
    (let ((next-num (function num)))
      (if (close-enough? num next-num)
          next-num
          (evaluate next-num (+ 1 iteration-num)))))
  (evaluate starting-guess 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like `num` you just add it a a parameter to your loop function:

```
(define (fixed-point function starting-guess)
  ;; prints progress
  (define (print-progress iter-count)
    (display iter-count)
    (display " - ") 
    (display num)
    (newline)) 

  ;; main calculating loop 
  (define (evaluate num iter-count)
    (print-progress iter-count)
    (let ((next-num (function num)))
      (if (close-enough? num next-num)
          next-num
          (evaluate next-num (+ iter-count 1)))))

  ;; start process with iter-count 1 since 
  ;; we do increments after display
  (evaluate starting-guess 1))
```

Notice that your version of this started displaying `0` while your `set!` version started with `1`. I compensated for this by starting off with `1` instead of `0`.

You could keep the side effects away from `fixed-point` completely by adding the functionality to the `function`:

```
;; pure functional fixed-point
(define (fixed-point function starting-guess)
  (define (evaluate num)
    (let ((next-num (function num)))
      (if (close-enough? num next-num)
          next-num
          (evaluate next-num))))
  (evaluate starting-guess))
    
;; makes a version of function that 
;; reports its first argument and 
;; number of times it's been called
(define (count-and-brag-calls f)
  ;; brag does whatever and
  ;; return the value
  (define (brag v c)
    (display c)
    (display " - ") 
    (display v)
    (newline)
    v) 

  ;; actual implementation
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda (n)
      (set! count (+ count 1))
      (brag (f n) count))))

;; with verbose output
(fixed-point (count-and-brag-calls cos) 1.0)

;; without side effects gives exact same result without output
(fixed-point cos 1.0)
```

Comment: thanks, what does "brag" mean? I've never heard it used like that in that context.

Comment: @David542 Bragging: To speak of with excessive pride or vanity. I found it a pleasing name since the function without will just do its job while adding `count-and-brag` will "brag" about how many times it's been called each time it gets called and the current return value :-) BTW: I'm Norwegian and not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

For the minimal edit, just move the *counter's* definition (binding) into the top level, and reset the *counter* each time before *you* make a call to `fixed-point`:

```
(define iter-count 0)  ;; here

(define (fixed-point function starting-guess)
  ;; (define iter-count 0)  ;; commented-out
  ....
  ....
  )

(begin
  (set! iter-count 0)
  (fixed-point ... ... ))
```